# Active Directory Powershell script only works after opening source csv in Excel

Tags: .net, excel, powershell, csv, active-directory

I am trying to update Active Directory with a PowerShell script.  I have a CSV file generated from a .NET console application that looks like it's perfectly fine when viewing it in .txt, and it opens in Excel without issue

**The Problem**

When I run the following PowerShell script, the AD gets updated and looks as I expect, however the users are not able to match their accounts.  I've tried different delimiters and changing the encoding to be explicitly UTF-8 and ANSI without success, and given I am unfamiliar with PowerShell and ActiveDirectory, I'm not sure what else to try.

**Strange Clue**

If I first open the .csv file from the console application in Excel and just save it right away, the update script works and users are able to match their accounts.  I thought this was the encoding but that doesn't seem to be it.  I've diffed the files both pre and post excel and they are identical.

Sample CSV Data:

```
last_name,first_name,altSecurityIdentities,userPrincipalName
DOE,JOHN,"x,y,z=y,<S>,0000000",jdoe@gmail.com
```

The console application builds the CSV by the following:

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter = ",";
csv.appendLine(string.Format("last_name{0}first_name{0}altSecurityIdentities{0}userPrincipalName{0}", delimiter));
for(UserRecord r in records){
     csv.appendLine(string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}\"{3}\"{0}{4}{0}", delimiter, r.lastName, r.firstName, r.altSecIdentity, r.email));
}
File.WriteAllText(fileName, csv.ToString());
```

The PowerShell script is:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
 [string]$FilePath
)
$LogDate = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
import-module ActiveDirectory
$names = import-csv $FilePath

foreach($name in $names){

try{
    $regularuser = get-aduser ($name.userPrincipalName -split "@")[0]
    $regularuser | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $name.userPrincipalName -Replace @{'altSecurityIdentities'=$name.altSecurityIdentities}
    $name.userPrincipalName + $name.altSecurityIdentities + " account updated" >> "regular_accounts-$logDate.txt"
    try{
        $adminname = "_"+(($name.userPrincipalName -split "@")[0])
        $adminuser = get-aduser $adminname
        $adminuser | Set-ADUser -Replace @{'altSecurityIdentities'=$name.altSecurityIdentities}
        "_"+(($name.userPrincipalName -split "@")[0]) + $name.altSecurityIdentities + " admin account updated" >> "admin_accounts-$logDate.txt"
    }
    catch{
        "_"+(($name.userPrincipalName -split "@")[0])+" admin account not found" >> "admin_accounts-$logDate.txt"
        "__"+(($name.userPrincipalName -split "@")[0])+" admin account not found" >> "admin__accounts-$logDate.txt"
         }
    }
catch{
    $name.userPrincipalName + " account not found" >> "regular_accounts-$logDate.txt"
     }
}
```

**EDIT - 'Solution'**

I'm not certain why at this point, but editing the PowerShell line:

```
$names = import-csv $FilePath
```

...and changing it to:

```
$names = import-csv $FilePath | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

...fixed whatever issue ActiveDirectory was having with the input.  Everything still looks the same, but however the login tool that matches users now works fine.

Comment: At first glance I can see you are not creating a valid CSV. The field `altSecurityIdentities` contains a string that has the delimiter as part of the value. It should be quoted. P.s. In the code you are not showing us if `delimiter` even HAS a value..

Comment: Again, you are NOT creating a valid CSV.. This time you don't write the correct headers in there while you intend to use them in the code afterwards (`$name.userPrincipalName`, `$name.userPrincipalName` etc.). The headers in your CSV are `col1`, `col2` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I used pseudocode for the .NET part, but I edited it now to reflect exactly what's happening.   The .NET program outputs the CSV sample shown above, which looks valid, looks fine when opened in Excel, and does update ActiveDirectory with the correct fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain why at this point, but editing the PowerShell line:

```
$names = import-csv $FilePath
```

...and changing it to:

```
$names = import-csv $FilePath | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

...fixed whatever issue ActiveDirectory was having with the input.  Everything still looks the same, but however the login tool that matches users now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the following code snippet may help you to identify the user running each one of the processes:

```
 $owners = @{}
 gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}

 get-process | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

I would suspect the CSV creation process (user) is different to the second one, can't test at the moment unfortunately

Good luck!